# Unreachable code detected in C#.Net

Tags: c#

I'm getting `unreachable code` warning in **catch block** and I'm not able to debug. Please suggest me how to rectify that bug:

```
private void HandleDevelopmentServer()
{
    string sErrMsg = "";
    try
    {
        QuasarInterfaces.ISecurity oSecurity = null;
        Global.CreateSecurityComponent(ref oSecurity);
        System.Data.DataSet oDS;
        DataTable dtDBSettings = new DataTable();
        string sDBString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Environment"];
        Global.ReadDBConfig(sDBString, ref dtDBSettings);
        oSecurity.FetchAllUsers(out oDS, out sErrMsg, dtDBSettings)

        if (sErrMsg.Length > 0) 
            throw new Exception(sErrMsg);              

        if ((oDS != null) && (oDS.Tables.Count != 0))
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = oDS;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("HandleDevelopmentServer function failed;" + e.Message);               
        Global.writeLog("" + e.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the logging before the throwing of the exception.

Comment: Um, don't try to log *after* you've thrown an exception? How do you expect the `Global.writeLog` method call to ever work? (You should learn about .NET naming conventions, btw.)

Comment: As stated in the error message the `Global.writeLog("" + e.ToString());` part is not reachable because you're throwing an exception before without handling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line will never happen:

```
Global.writeLog("" + e.ToString());
```

You are throwing an exception just above it, meaning this method will exit at that point to the previous in the call stack

By just switching the two it will be fine.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Global.writeLog("" + e.ToString());
    throw new Exception("HandleDevelopmentServer function failed;" + e.Message);               
}
```

*And you can also remove the `"" +`.*

Comment: @Ganesh Chemanchula - Did this help you to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes Gilad !! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to switch the two lines in the catch block so that the log is written before the exception is thrown.